# System does not boot, just a black screen after uninstalling/removing smth

Tags: boot

04 doesnt boot anymore. It starts up normally, BIOS works, but I don't see the Ubuntu-Logo or the Login Screen, just a lighted black screen. No Error or smth is displayed. The system doesnt react to any input. Before shutting down the system earlier today I applied some changes to it (I believe, I broke something by not thinking before acting -.- ):
- Unistalled of Ubuntu One, first via Software Center, then deleting entrys with ubuntuo one via Synaptics
- sudo apt-get autoremove 
- Using "Aufräumen" (Clean?) (sorry, German, maybe "manager") from Ubuntu Tweak (It deleted some old Kernels and stuff the system "doesn't need" )
- Installation of OwnCloud Clients and 'tray'

I think thats all I changed recently, I was using it the whole morning!

I think Ill have to post some details or logs but I don't know which ones AND how to get them :(

Id be happy if somebody helps me:)

Thank you!

Raphael

Answer (score 0):

Does your system boot but you simply cannot see anything ?
Did you try to go to a console with CTRL+ALT+F1 ? Or on a german keyboard STRG+ALT+F1 ?
From this you can move on if it works.
Makku